# Wait till request finished Qt

Tags: c++, qt

My program is getting data from mysql table via json format through php script, that generating json.

My function sends to server post request (with some params) and getting response. With that all okay. Works fine.
But, when I want to get specified cell (data from json array), it takes empty string (program works fast and taking data from a string before it sets up)

Here's the code with post request:

```
void dbase::requestor(QString option)
{
    curr_js = ""; //nulling string
    QString urla = host+"transfer.php";
    // /////////
    QNetworkAccessManager * manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QUrl url(urla);
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    QUrlQuery params;
    params.addQueryItem("api", key);
    params.addQueryItem("option", option);
    //QEventLoop loop;
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));
    //loop.exec(); tryed eventloop, but bcuz of this my replyFinished is not accessible. error code under this one
    manager->post(request, params.query().toUtf8());

}
```

If using eventloop

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QEventLoop::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)
```

replyFinished function (setting up variable)

```
void dbase::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    curr_js = reply->readAll();
}
```

Usage (where is problem)

```
    QString req = "SOME REQUEST";
    database.requestor(req);
    if (database.db_cell (0,0) == "")
    {
        qDebug()<<database.db_cell (0,0) << " - EMPTY - "<<database.curr_js;
    }
```

So in this case I'm getting

```
""  - EMPTY -  ""
```

But if I getting data from string (created button for test), it's there:

```
{"0":["1", "Admin","hashpwd"],"1":["2", "Albert","hashpwd"]}
```

db_cell function

```
QString dbase::db_cell (int indexrow, int indexcols)
{
    QJsonDocument sd = QJsonDocument::fromJson(curr_js.toUtf8());
    QJsonObject setobj = sd.object();
    QJsonValue qqq = setobj.value(QString(QString::number(indexrow))).toArray()[indexcols];
    return qqq.toString();
}
```

As I see, problem is that program need to wait before getting a data from json-string.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Don't explicitly wait, c send the request and continue using the result once replyFinished() is called.

Comment: it almost minimal. 
I have class which working with requests and getting data from mysql through php-json.

so problem that "database.db_cell" getting curr_js variable too fast, before it fills by replyFinished. that's all

Comment: Frank, yes, but when 1 variable must be set up by 1 function for using in 2 function, second function getting this var before 1 function setting up.